# NodeJS, bypass URL length limitation

Tags: node.js

It seems NodeJS only allows URLs of max. size 80KB.

I need to pass longer URLs to an internal application, is that possible to bypass that limitation without recompiling NodeJs (which is impossible for me on the setup).

Comment: 80KB are more,more than 50000 of characters. Are you sure that you need the url (GET) for that ? Is there possible to send that with POST ?

Comment: No, POST is not possible :(

Comment: then you have to modify the `http_parser.h` from `node.js`,  search by `HTTP_MAX_HEADER_SIZE`. https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/blob/v0.10.33/deps/http_parser/http_parser.h

Comment: To change the maximum header size, define the macro in the build environment (e.g. -DHTTP_MAX_HEADER_SIZE=<value>). [source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/db1087c9757c31a82c50a1eba368d8cba95b57d0/deps/http_parser/http_parser.h#L64)

Comment: This seems like I need to recompile/build nodejs? Not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the limit without modifing the `http_parser.h` file.

You will need a better way of sending the data to your application whether it be in the request body or a file within the request body. Without more information it is difficult to propose a solution to your problem